# KNN in sklearn - How to appropriately use KNeighborsRegressor in a class?

Tags: scikit-learn, knn

I have written two versions of a K-nearest-neighbor model. The difference of the two is only in that the data is split into training and testing set in the second but all data are used in the first (no training/testing). Both use part of the same dataset as below.

**Features data (X)**

```
[[33.499313000000001, 33.499313000000001], [43.238892999999997, 43.238892999999997], [43.252267000000003, 43.252267000000003], [43.251044999999998, 43.251044999999998], [43.2408748, 43.2408748], [42.9685074, 42.9685074], [43.030356099999999, 43.030356099999999], [43.014093000000003, 43.014093000000003], [43.017124000000003, 43.017124000000003], [43.017701000000002, 43.017701000000002], [43.015931000000002, 43.015931000000002], [43.013155699999999, 43.013155699999999], [43.014164000000001, 43.014164000000001], [43.017938700000002, 43.017938700000002], [43.093265000000002, 43.093265000000002], [43.090642000000003, 43.090642000000003], [43.0910607, 43.0910607], [43.110157100000002, 43.110157100000002], [43.077415000000002, 43.077415000000002], [43.096271000000002, 43.096271000000002], [43.103071900000003, 43.103071900000003], [43.100384099999999, 43.100384099999999], [43.0954975, 43.0954975], [43.092902899999999, 43.092902899999999], [43.091816000000001, 43.091816000000001], [43.096359, 43.096359], [43.107227000000002, 43.107227000000002], [43.101459800000001, 43.101459800000001], [43.075345267735997, 43.075345267735997], [43.103663300000001, 43.103663300000001], [43.100808000000001, 43.100808000000001], [43.090563099999997, 43.090563099999997], [43.090455900000002, 43.090455900000002], [43.095485500000002, 43.095485500000002], [43.103427000000003, 43.103427000000003], [43.090653000000003, 43.090653000000003], [43.082611, 43.082611], [43.0901268, 43.0901268], [43.095695999999997, 43.095695999999997], [43.095552599999998, 43.095552599999998], [43.087887000000002, 43.087887000000002], [43.108379900000003, 43.108379900000003], [43.106097200000001, 43.106097200000001], [43.092882000000003, 43.092882000000003], [43.095547199999999, 43.095547199999999], [43.099933499999999, 43.099933499999999], [43.092684599999998, 43.092684599999998], [43.107769300000001, 43.107769300000001], [43.096947399999998, 43.096947399999998], [43.094959000000003, 43.094959000000003], [43.104534999999998, 43.104534999999998], [43.099418399999998, 43.099418399999998], [43.095357, 43.095357], [43.097688300000002, 43.097688300000002], [43.057022699999997, 43.057022699999997], [43.092902899999999, 43.092902899999999], [43.095723999999997, 43.095723999999997], [43.075383000000002, 43.075383000000002], [43.057089900000001, 43.057089900000001], [43.084459600000002, 43.084459600000002]]
```

**Response data (y)**

```
[3.5, 4.0, 4.0, 4.5, 4.0, 1.5, 2.0, 2.5, 4.5, 3.5, 5.0, 1.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.5, 4.5, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 4.0, 3.5, 4.0, 3.5, 3.5, 3.0, 3.0, 5.0, 3.0, 3.0, 2.5, 3.5, 4.0, 5.0, 3.5, 2.5, 4.0, 2.5, 3.5, 3.5, 4.0, 1.5, 4.0, 4.5, 5.0, 4.0, 3.5, 2.0, 5.0, 5.0, 4.0, 3.5, 3.5, 4.0, 3.0, 3.0, 3.0]
```

**Import modules**

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor
from sklearn.cross_validation import KFold
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
```

**The first model - no split**

```
class LonLatClassifier(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
def __init__(self):
    pass

def fit(self, X, y):
    self.knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 9)
    self.knn.fit(X, y)
    return self        

def predict(self, X):
    return self.knn.predict(X)
```

As I test this model with the following code, it gives me a prediction score.

```
C = LonLatClassifier()
print(C.score(X, y))
```

**The second model - with split**

```
class LonLatClassifier(BaseEstimator, RegressorMixin):
def __init__(self, X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test):
    self.xtrain = X_train
    self.ytrain = y_train
    self.xtest = X_test
    self.ytest = y_test
    pass

def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
    self.knn = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors = 13)
    self.fit = self.knn.fit(self.xtrain, self.ytrain)
    return self

def predict(self, X_test):
    self.xtest = X_test
    return self.knn.predict(self.xtest)
```

In this model, as I run the following code, it does not give me prediction or score.

```
C = LonLatClassifier(X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test)
C.predict(X_test)
```

The error message is:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-52-ecf778e90264> in <module>()
----> 1 C.predict(X_test)

<ipython-input-47-aeee765d2615> in predict(self, X_test)
 14     def predict(self, X_test):
 15         self.xtest = X_test
---> 16         return self.knn.predict(self.xtest)
 17 

AttributeError: 'LonLatClassifier' object has no attribute 'knn'
```

I am not clear where it goes wrong, as the two models are only different in data spliting. Could someone help me identify the problem and give me a suggestion how to fix it? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am sorry for the confusion. It was only because I did not call C.fit() before calling C.predict() in the second model.

I am not sure if this information is useful to a greater audience in stackoverflow. Please let me know and I can take it down. Thank you.